# Basic question on inner product and norms

Tags: inner-products

If $x = (f,g)$ is a vector in $\mathbb{C}^2$. such that $\|x\|^2 = |f|^2 + |g|^2 = 1$
Define the operator $T: \mathbb{C}^2 \to\mathbb{C}^2$ as $Tx = (g,0)$, then $\langle Tx, x\rangle = g\bar{f}$. 
Why does this 
$|\langle Tx,x \rangle| = |g| |f|\leq \frac{1}{2} (|f|^2 + |g|^2)$ hold?

Comment: I know that $|\langle Tx, x \rangle| \leq \|Tx\|^2 \|x\|^2$. I don't see where is the $\frac{1}{2}$ coming from.

Comment: Young's inequality.

Comment: Ah, I did not know this one. So, this is a result for any two numbers $a,b$, we have that $|ab| \leq \frac{|a|^2}{2} + \frac{|b|^2}{2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\dfrac{|f|^2 + |g|^2}{2} - |g||f| = \dfrac{\left(|f| - |g|\right)^2}{2} \geq 0$

Answer (score 1):

For all complex numbers $a$ and $b$ we have

$$\left(|a|-|b|\right)^2\ge0\iff |a||b|\le\frac12\left(|a|^2+|b|^2\right)$$